# How and where should I store the conversion code for image files in Django?

Tags: python, django, image

I created a simple form in Django of which it contains only a single form input field i.e image field. My aim is to allow a user to upload an image file i.e JPEG, JPG, SVG, PNG. Once uploaded, I want to write some code that'll convert the image file to PNG and then store it in my database. How should I write this code and where do I write it? You can view my current code below. I'm a beginner in Django and could use some help.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**website/urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),

]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
"""Image upload model"""
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media', default = 'media/sample.png')
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from myapp.models import Image

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Image upload form"""
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ('created_date',)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
from myapp.forms import ImageForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from PIL import Image

class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"

class ImageView(CreateView):
    template_name = "insert_image.html"
    form_class = ImageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("base")
```

**insert_image.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Insert an image </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Please upload an image below </h1>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Thanks! </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Thanks for uploading! </h1>
    <button> <a href = '{% url "insert_image" %}' style="text-decoration: 
    none;"> Return </button> </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the exact way you can do please reply back if you face any problen and do vote my answer :--

```
from django.db import models
import os
from PIL import Image

class Image(models.Model):
"""Image upload model"""
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_directory_path, default = 'media/sample.png')
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)

def get_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if file_extension[1] in ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg']:
        filename=file_extension[0]+'.png'
        dir = 'Images'
    else:
        dir="others"
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, filename)
    return path
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Can you explain your code though? Why did you give dir = 'Images' or 'others' in the conditional statements?

Comment: I'm getting an error which states: 'NameError: 'get_directory_path' is not defined.'

Comment: Use get_directory_path inside ur model class and check spelling as well

Comment: The purpose of giving dir =image  or dir =others is to segregate image in image dir and doc files in other dir

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: NameError: name 'get_directory_path' is not defined. I think you should pass some parameters when you call the method. Or, can we use the property method instead?

Comment: It worked! but I recommend you to add the method code above the Model. The reason why get_directory_path wasn't defined was that the method was written below it. Thank you

Comment: How do you allow SVG files to be added though? It doesnt seem to accept SVG files @Abhisek Singh

Comment: if you write this get_directory_path function inside your model class and then call it ,would not throw error

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "pyrsvg" - a Python binding for librsvg.

There is an Ubuntu python-rsvg package providing it. Searching Google for its name is poor because its source code seems to be contained inside the "gnome-python-desktop" Gnome project GIT repository.

I made a minimalist "hello world" that renders SVG to a cairo surface and writes it to disk:

```
from django.db import models
import os
from PIL import Image

class Image(models.Model):
"""Image upload model"""
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_directory_path, default = 'media/sample.png')
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)

def get_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if file_extension[1] in ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg','.svg']:
        if file_extension[1] != '.svg':
            filename=file_extension[0]+'.png'
            dir = 'Images'
        else:

            import cairo
            import rsvg

            img = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 640,480)

            ctx = cairo.Context(img)

            ## handle = rsvg.Handle(<svg filename>)
            # or, for in memory SVG data:
            handle= rsvg.Handle(None, str(<svg data>))

            handle.render_cairo(ctx)
            filename=img.write_to_png("svg.png")
            dir = 'Images'

    else:
        dir="others"
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, filename)
    return path
```

Update: as of 2014 the needed package for Fedora Linux distribution is: gnome-python2-rsvg. The above snippet listing still works as-is.

Answer (score 0):

In your ImageView class you can override form_valid

```
class ImageView(CreateView):
[...]
def form_valid(self, form):
        uploaded_image = form.instance
        [do your convert code here]
        return super(ImageView, self).form_valid(form)
```

you could also use post_save signal.